# Relative path of node_modules for LESS @import

Tags: less

Say I have the following structure

```
/node_modules
/src
   /components
      /component1
         /style
            /style.less
```

Now I want to import some LESS file from `node_modules/some-module/style.less`; I'd have to do something like `@import '../../../../node_modules/some-module/style.less`

Is there no short hand notation so that the path is relative to project folder? Something like `@import ~/node_modules/some-module/style.less`?

Comment: [`less-plugin-npm-import`](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-npm-import).

Comment: What if it's a private module?

Comment: I can't see how private/not-private can change anything.

Comment: It's the it loading the packages from npm? My package is hosted on enterprise github account

Comment: If by "loading from npm" you mean something like "npm install" then no, it has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve this by installing **less-loader** and add it into webpack.

How to do it:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-loader#webpack-resolver

Example:

```
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```